# Create Jar file with IntelliJ IDEA that has mysql database

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executable-jar

I want to create (export) my application into a Jar file to be portable.

How can i put my database contents with jar file?

For e.g for pictures, i put pictures folder beside my jar file, and it shows pictures correctly.

**UPDATE**

A peace of code to connect to database:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Library", "root", "1234");
```

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: What do you mean 'that has MySQL data'?  Do you mean the jar contains the driver for MySQL or the scripts/data that make up the database?

Comment: Please specify what exactly you want to embed in your jar file. A file tree of images or other normal files? A MySQL database dump? A MySQL driver? A running MySQL server (hint: this one is practically impossible)?

Comment: @NickHolt my IDE has driver for MySQL, and now in don't know that my Jar file has that driver or no!

Comment: @EmilLundberg My program used a simple database to save data, and also use images in graphical interface.

Comment: @Sajjad You're still not answering my question.

Comment: @EmilLundberg i don't running MySQL server, my application is written is java SE (desktop application, particular a library program).

Comment: If you're not using a MySQL database (or any other SQL database, I'll assume) then what exactly is this "database" you're referring to?

Comment: Could you please share the piece of code where you connect to 'database'?

Comment: @EmilLundberg I don't say that i don't use mysql MySQL database, I use MySqL database, and install it's driver to my IDE.

Comment: @Sajjad : A piece of friendly advice. If you are new to Java, stay away from IDEs, use a good text editor like vim. That way you will learn more. IDEs hide out a lot of stuff which you need to understand. For example, where is your MySQL installation, which mysql driver are you using, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393397/embedding-mysql-in-java-desktop-application

Comment: Perhaps better possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791417/java-mysql-is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-mysql-server-with-a-java-program?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to distribute a copy of your database with each copy of your application, I think using MySQL will be a bit complicated. You may want to look into using a database system designed to be embedded, such as [SQLite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm), instead. A complete SQLite database is a single text file - you'd simply distribute your one `mydatabase.db` file along with the jar. See the examples at the above link.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you could use:

**Approach 1**
Do you really need to use database? If not, store your data on files in file system, that way you can easily export it with data.

**Approach 2**
Bundle the mysql installation directory in your jar / installer. Write a scripts which starts up both MySQL server and you application.

Comment: I am Java programmer about one year, I should use your second approach, but HOW?

Comment: Give it a try on your own, you have enough clues. That's how you learn.

Comment: @Sajjad: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791417/java-mysql-is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-mysql-server-with-a-java-program). I think you're probably better off using a database system designed to be embedded, though, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20430595/833844).