# how to run process within process?

Tags: java, process, mysql

I have created a java application in which i am using MySQL server.
When I run project then three process start

1. mysqld.exe
2. java.exe
3. FirstApplication.exe

I run MySQL server externally by executing mysqld process.
But I want to merge process mysqld.exe in FirstApplication.exe process means when this FirstApplication.exe process starts then automatically internally mysqld.exe process should be start(run as one process).
I want only 2 process in task manager

1. java.exe
2. FirstApplication.exe

I do not know is this possible or not? Please Suggest any answer.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393397/embedding-mysql-in-java-desktop-application

Comment: I do not want mysqld.exe process in task manager.It should be run as subprocess in FirstApplication.exe.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [libmysqld](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/libmysqld.html), but since it's a C/C++ library you'd have to call it with either JNI or [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) (JNA is probably easier).

Be aware that the free version of MySQL is GPL licensed so doing this would require you to distribute your application's sources to your end-users.

Comment: can you elaborate with any program